# RoutingError on "/users/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following routing error when I click on logout from my application where the authentication is managed with devise 3.2.2 .

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

this is the haml line generating the link.

```
%li= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete')
```

this is the html generated:

```
<a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>
```

this is the log for the call:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-09 22:04:34 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"):
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

this used to work in the past, I'm not sure what happened and why it's not working any more.

any clues?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using `method: 'delete'` requires the inclusion of `jquery_ujs` (for browsers that don't support data-method).

Verify that you're loading `application.js` and that that file includes the line `//= require jquery_ujs`

Comment: thanks, I have the `ujs` required in my `application.js`. more clues?

Comment: nop, no errors, just a few warnings: body.scrollTop deprecated, body.scrollLeft deprecated and event.returnValue deprecated. none of them in the ujs, I see the problem both in production and in development and I'm using the assets pipeline

Comment: Can you verify that UJS is being loaded in your app.js? It should probably be up near the top, with a top comment of `/**
 * Unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery
 * https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs`

Comment: verified, the file is included both in production and in development. it's near the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find why the UJS wasn't working in this case generating the proper request with method delete, I suspect this is chrome related.

I worked this around changing:

config.sign_out_via = :get

in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

this now works.